# Serving static files with NGINX and DJANGO

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, static, static-files

I'm new to programming and I've managed to build my father a website where he can showcase his photography, I recently had to switch from shared hosting to my own VPS that uses ubuntu to give me more control and access to latest pips.

I've had everything working on local server regarding static files, everything uploads where it is meant to(for me it was static/media).

In production I've got my website running perfectly other than any css working for my templates or even admin panel and images not showing.

I have ran the following commands to get where I am, I will so share some code and screenshots of current configuration also. Image folders are also been created rather than images going into media folder. Images in browser have extensions image/image/test4 also.

```
DEBUG = False

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/dave/mhprints/static

sudo chmod -R 777 /home/dave/mhprints/static

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/dave/mhprints/staticfiles

sudo chmod -R 777 /home/dave/mhprints/staticfiles

sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/staticfiles

sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/staticfiles
```

I have ImageField set with upload_to='media'

**Current mapping of my project**

[image: project mapping]

**Mapping of VAR folder**

[image: var mapping]

**ROOTS AND URLS in settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    ]
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
```

**URLS.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('mhpapp.urls')),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**sites_enabled/mhprints file**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_ip;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static {
            root /var/www;
        }
    location /media {
            root /var/www/static;
        }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

I hope there is enough information here for some one to help me with this puzzle. I'm hoping its something simple I have over looked.

Comment: So where are your files: here `/home/dave/mhprints/static`, here `/var/www/staticfiles` or here `/var/www/static`? What do you call an "extension" here: `image/image/test4`? Can you share specific error messages from nginx or django error log file?

Comment: Hi Ivan, currently I have one test image which I uploaded to test which when uploaded endedup in a created folder static/images/images. I currently have css style sheets stored in static/css, when i collect static they go into staticfiles/images/imagses amd staticfiles/css .sorry by extension I mean the url, so when I open image in new tab the end of the url shows image/image/test4. I don't see any errors been displayed? Unless I'm not looking in the right place? Could you direct me where to look?

Comment: I created the var/directories thinking it linked with my other directories by the way so my static files are literally everywhere this why I need advice on the correct pathing, I should maybe delete some directorie?

Comment: Please stop _telling stories_, ask an [answerable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and focus on a [reproducible problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can and should be fixed. Your setup is unclear, the problem is unclear. 403? 404? you don't like image urls?